# How to reference a file inside my Test project to load w/o hard coded the path?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file-io, nunit

In my nunit test project I have a layout like:

```
/Fixters/someFile.txt
/Services/SomeService.cs
```

someFile.txt is a file that I need to read as it contains text that I use for my unit tests.

How can I reference this folder without hard coding the path as other team members may store this project at a different path that me.

Comment: Please note that you are not doing a unit test if you rely on dependencies like this. That being said, for your integration tests, we will need some code to see what you are doing? You should be able to pass relative references as you have listed.

Comment: Would you be able to use a network folder to store the files? You can all just reference the network path.

Comment: Accessing a network drive during tests that run often doesn't sound so good to me.

Comment: @JustinPihony the file has string values that I need to test my methods with, its just sample input data.

Comment: But, you have now created a reason for a unit test to fail for reasons beyond the test itself. This can be dangerous to unit test reliability.

Comment: @JustinPihony, disagree.  It's perfectly reasonable to use test input data from a file in a unit test.  Test files can be a way of _avoiding_ integration tests by, say, putting a test JSON response from a 3rd party in the file rather than actually making the call to the 3rd party.

Comment: @jreancsu Why does it have to be a file?

Comment: @JustinPihony Suppose you have a large string that you want to test against....or maybe you want to have a really large number of test cases.  It would be much better organized to throw it into a txt or JSON file (or w/e) than to have all that live as constants inside the same file as your TestFixture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do `File.ReadAllText(filepath)` and any other equivalent method where you pass in a relative path, the runtime will use the app's current working directory to create the whole path. So generally speaking, you should be fine using relative paths. You might also need to specify that `someFile.txt` gets copied to the output directory.

If unsure what the cwd is, try `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

Comment: Matt, that gives me a path to bin/debug/ folder, not sure how to get out of that folder and into the /Fixtures folder.

Comment: That's where copying the fixtures into the output directory comes into play. I don't have Visual Studio handy right now, but if you right click the fixture file and go to its properties, there will be a build step called "Copy to output directory if newer" or something like that. Then your fixture will by in the same place as your test when it's running